# What is this syntax for creating an object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm reading about mixins [here](https://javascript.info/mixins) and it uses this valid code:

```js
let sayHiMixin = {
  sayHi() {
    alert(`Hello ${this.name}`);
  },
  sayBye() {
    alert(`Bye ${this.name}`);
  }
};

console.log(sayHiMixin);
```

`sayHiMixin` is a valid object. Can anyone point out to me how the syntax for writing this object is valid (maybe an MDN page)? I've never seen it before except for when writing methods in a class.

Comment: object properties can be anything, including functions

Comment: *"maybe an MDN page"* - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer?

Comment: It's *almost* similar to `let sayHiMixin = { sayHi: function() { alert("Hello") } `

Comment: MDN calls them ["Shorthand method names"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)